# Compilation error with std::find when trying to fetch user defined objects from std::vector

Tags: c++11, vector

I am trying to create a basic application which is modeling "sticky notes" activity. This would contain functions to add notes and delete notes. Below is the code. In deleteNote function, I am finding the title in the vector of Notes which is given as an input argument using std::find method. The std::find API is throwing compilation errors. Below is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

using InitializerTags = std::initializer_list<std::string>;
using TupleObject = std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string>;

class Note
{
public:
    TupleObject m_tags;

    Note(std::string title, std::string text, std::string tags){
        std::cout<< "parameterized Constructor"<< std::endl;
        m_tags  =  std::make_tuple(title, text, tags);
    }

    /*Note(const Note& rhs){
        std:: cout << "copy constructor"<< std::endl;
        m_tags = rhs.m_tags;
    }*/

    Note(Note&& rhs){
        std::cout<< "move constructor"<< std::endl;
        m_tags = rhs.m_tags;
    }

    Note& operator=(Note&& rhs){
        std::cout << "move assignment"<< std::endl;
        if(this != &rhs){
            m_tags = rhs.m_tags;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Note() = delete;
    Note(const Note& rhs) = delete;
    Note& operator=(const Note& rhs) = delete;

    ~Note(){

    }
};

class Storyboard
{
private:
    std::vector <Note> m_notes;
public:

    /*Storyboard(){
        m_notes.reserve(1);
    }*/

    void addNote(std::string title, std::string text, std::string tags)
    {
        std::cout << "inside addNote"<< std::endl;
        m_notes.emplace_back(title, text, tags);
    }

    void deleteNote(std::string title)
    {
        for(auto& x: m_notes){
            if(std::get<0>(x.m_tags) == title){
                m_notes.erase(std::find(m_notes.begin(),m_notes.end(), x));
            }
        }
    }


    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "Inside print"<< std::endl;
        for(auto& x : m_notes){
            std::cout << std::get<0>(x.m_tags)<< " ";
            std::cout << std::get<1>(x.m_tags)<< " ";
            std::cout << std::get<2>(x.m_tags)<< " ";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Below is the error.

In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
from StoryBoard.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of ‘bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<_Value>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Note*, std::vector >; _Value = const Note]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:120:14:   required from ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Predicate, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Note*, std::vector >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:161:23:   required from ‘_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Note*, std::vector >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:3790:28:   required from ‘_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Note*, std::vector >; _Tp = Note]’
StoryBoard.cpp:67:73:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:194:17: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘Note’ and ‘const Note’)
{ return *__it == _M_value; }

I checked the files in which the error occurred.

The problem has occurred with the signature of std::find which is
std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&)

The 3rd input argument is being taken as **const reference** and this is being compared with non const reference in predefined_ops.h:194.

I am trying to understand what in my code led to this situation.

Also trying to figure out the fix.

Any help which would clear my understanding would be appreciated.

Comment: This part of the error messages seems to be the most relevant: "error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘Note’ and ‘const Note’)" In short, you have no way to compare two `Note` objects for equality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
std::find(m_notes.begin(),m_notes.end(), x)
```

`std::find` algorithm tries to compare an element from `m_notes` with `x`, but you didn't provide `operator==` which does it, hence error message. Becuase you are erasing elements based on title, you can write:

```
class Note
{
public:
    //...

    // comparison operator as member function
    bool operator == (const Note& theOther) const {
        // compare titles
        return std::get<0>(m_tags) == std::get<0>(theOther.m_tags);
    }
    //...
};
```

then the code compiles, but probably it will crash.
You are using range-based for loop which checks `vector::end` iterator but it may be invalidated when `vector::erase` is called. [See how range-for is implemented and how `end` is used.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Now you are iterating over all elements in vector and if title matches to `title` you are calling `find` to find element to be removed. It is overkill, you can go over vector with iterator and when title is matched just call `erase` algorithm for the current iterator without re-iterating vector by `find`:

Rewrite `deleteNote` into something like this:

```
void deleteNote(std::string title)
{
    for (auto it = m_notes.begin(); it != m_notes.end(); )
    {
        if(std::get<0>(it->m_tags) == title)
            it = m_notes.erase(it); // returns the first element past the removed one
        else 
            ++it;
    }
}
```

---

If you want to move `rhs.m_tags;` in move ctor and move assignment operator you need to cast *rhs.m_tags* to Rreference - `m_tags = std::move(rhs.m_tags);`.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude  and @rafix07 thanks a lot for the inputs given.